# How resource heavy is sending an AJAX request on a setTimeout() function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, resources

I'm going to create a live chat system for my website, but I'm not sure how to go about it. My original plan was to have an AJAX request to get the chat log every X seconds, and that's what it seems a lot of tutorials have done.

However, I'm worried that by doing this, I might use up my server's resources unnecessarily, or very quickly. I want my chat to be quite accurate, so I guess my question is, what's the most appropriate time in milliseconds I should wait between each ping to not use up my server's resources while keeping my chat log accurate?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something powerfull, try to look into websockets. You can find some intuitive libraries like socket.io.

Otherwise it's ok to use ajax on a setTimeout and do some research about ajax polling wich is the best technology to use in that case.